# Latest changes in C11

Tags: c, standards, c11

C1x has become ISO/IEC 9899:2011 aka C11.

Does anyone know what changes (if any) there are in the Standard from the [April 2011 draft n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)?

ETA:  There are the Committee minutes from London (March 2011) (which should be included in n1570) [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1587.pdf), and from Washington, DC (October 2011) [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1588.pdf); I suppose a list of accepted changes in the DC minutes should cover things.

Comment: according to a comment by Larry Jones on comp.std.c there were no significant changes from N1569 (which is N1570 without change markers). The only thing that remains unsolved is the value for `__STDC_VERSION__`, but I guess most naturally it will be `201112L`.

Comment: Thanks for that info, @JensGustedt.  BTW, I linked to n1570 because that link is publicly accessible; n1569 can be downloaded as well, but not directly.

Comment: @JohanBezem, they even forgot that? So we can issue the first defect report :) Luckily this uses just integers, so anything by testing against `201100L` should be safe.

Comment: @JensGustedt I just deleted my own comment, since you already described the situation, nothing to add there. I assume this is normal for a 'first release', since the ISO process is quite convoluted, and you never know if it will be through before Christmas, but you have to provide the final proof-ready document. I guess we'd better use it as you suggest like `< 201100L` or `>= 201101L`. But I guess this is not considered a defect.

Comment: I am also reading the n1570 in detail and investigating differences between it and the final Standard. I concentrate mainly on the final [type hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448882/understanding-the-c11-type-hierarchy) of the language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just learned today that there was one (somewhat) significant change between N1570 and the final C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)).

In N1570, 6.3.2p3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
> operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
> initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is
> converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

The inclusion of `_Alignof` was an error, since the syntax of a *unary-expression* permits

```
_Alignof ( type-name )
```

but not

```
_Alignof unary-expression
```

The released C11 standard corrects this error and reverts to the C99 wording:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an
> expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

More information: in a recent posting to comp.std.c about differences between N1570 and the released standard, Larry Jones, a member of the ISO C committee, wrote:

> There are a number of them, but most are just minor editorial tweaks,
> changes to boilerplate text, and shuffling things around to keep the
> powers that be happy. The biggest change was removing _Alignof from a
> bunch of places it shouldn't have been added (based on the erroneous
> notion that it takes either a type or an expression like sizeof does
> when it really only takes a type): 6.3.2.1p2, p3, p4, fn. 65; and
> 6.7.1 fn. 121.

Message-ID: `<rfg33a-u0q.ln1@jones.homeip.net>`

Here's [the thread](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.std.c/c/v5hsWOu5vSw) as seen on groups.google.com.

Answer (score 5):

Answered by [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) in the comments:

> According to a comment by Larry Jones on comp.std.c there were no significant changes from N1569 (which is N1570 without change markers). The only thing that remains unsolved is the value for `__STDC_VERSION__`, but I guess most naturally it will be `201112L`.

Comment: The official 2011 standard left `__STDC_VERSION__` and the optional `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` incorrectly defined. The first Technical Corrigendum defined both as `201112L`.

Answer (score 1):

ISO has ratified and published as ISO/IEC 9899:2011 the new C11 (C1x) standard for the C programming language. The major changes from the previous standard (C99), as written in the [C11 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Changes_from_C99), are the following:

> The standard includes several changes to the C99 language and library specifications, such as:
>
> - Alignment specification (`_Alignas` specifier, `_Alignof` operator, `aligned_alloc` function, `<stdalign.h>` header file)
> - The `_Noreturn` function specifier
> - Type-generic expressions using the `_Generic` keyword. For example, the following macro `cbrt(x)` translates to `cbrtl(x)`, `cbrt(x)` or `cbrtf(x)` depending on the type of `x`:
>
>   ```
>       #define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), long double: cbrtl, \
>                                     default: cbrt, \
>                                     float: cbrtf)(X)
>   ```
> - Multithreading support (`_Thread_local` storage-class specifier, `<threads.h>` header including thread creation/management functions, mutex, condition variable and thread-specific storage functionality, as well as the `_Atomic` type qualifier and `<stdatomic.h>` for uninterruptible object access).
> - Improved Unicode support based on the C Unicode Technical Report ISO/IEC TR 19769:2004 (`char16_t` and `char32_t` types for storing UTF-16/UTF-32 encoded data, including conversion functions in `<uchar.h>` and the corresponding `u` and `U` string literal prefixes, as well as the `u8` prefix for UTF-8 encoded literals).
> - Removal of the `gets` function, deprecated in the previous C language standard revision, ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), in favor of a new safe alternative, `gets_s`.
> - Bounds-checking interfaces (Annex K).
> - Analyzability features (Annex L).
> - More macros for querying the characteristics of floating point types, concerning subnormal floating point numbers and the number of decimal digits the type is able to store.
> - Anonymous *structures* and *unions*, useful when unions and structures are nested, e.g. in `struct T { int tag; union { float x; int n; }; };`.
> - Static assertions, which are evaluated during translation at a later phase than `#if` and `#error`, when types are understood by the translator.
> - An exclusive create-and-open mode (`"…x"` suffix) for `fopen`. This behaves like `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` in POSIX, which is commonly used for lock files.
> - The `quick_exit` function as a third way to terminate a program, intended to do at least minimal deinitializition if termination with `exit` fails.
> - Macros for the construction of complex values (partly because `real + imaginary*I` might not yield the expected value if `imaginary` is infinite or NaN).

From the ISO site you can buy the [full published standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853). Here is an abstract taken from the ISO site:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 specifies the form and establishes the interpretation of programs written in the C programming language. It specifies
>
> - the representation of C programs;
> - the syntax and constraints of the C language;
> - the semantic rules for interpreting C programs;
> - the representation of input data to be processed by C programs;
> - the representation of output data produced by C programs;
> - the restrictions and limits imposed by a conforming implementation of C.
>
> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 does not specify
>
> - the mechanism by which C programs are transformed for use by a data-processing system;
> - the mechanism by which C programs are invoked for use by a data-processing system;
> - the mechanism by which input data are transformed for use by a C program;
> - the mechanism by which output data are transformed after being produced by a C program;
> - the size or complexity of a program and its data that will exceed the capacity of any specific data-processing system or the capacity of a particular processor;
> - all minimal requirements of a data-processing system that is capable of supporting a conforming implementation.
>     ISO/IEC 9899:2011 is designed to promote the portability of C programs among a variety of data-processing systems. It is intended for use by implementers and programmers.

Comment: This doesn't even try to answer the question asked, which had nothing to do with the differences between C11 and C99.

Comment: I agree with @MarkAmery. The question was about differences between N1570 and the final published C11.