# difference between c99 and c11

Tags: c, c99, c11

I am learning c, presently. [The book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504) I read is C99 based. I want to update my knowledge to C11 after finishing this book, or change resource if there is a major difference. Thus, what I ask is for is an explanation or resource to update my knowledge. I only found [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631228/latest-changes-in-c11). Nevertheless, it does not seem to encompass the information I need or not concise.

Thanks in advance.
P.S: I want to learn C11 since I think it is the prevalent standard now. If not, please inform me.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it too much at the current stage.

Comment: Well, there's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29).

Comment: About 12 years of improvements, after a lot of negotiations.  This primarily means additional features, which can be useful in specific situations; but, in order to keep C code portable to the next version, are mostly not likely to break any code you write in C99 or they'd lose their developer base.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Good overviews of C11 standard:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
- https://smartbear.com/blog/test-and-monitor/c11-a-new-c-standard-aiming-at-safer-programming/

The standard includes several changes to the C99 language and library specifications, such as:

- Alignment specification (`_Alignas` specifier, `_Alignof` operator, `aligned_alloc` function, `<stdalign.h>` header file)
- The `_Noreturn` function specifier and the `<stdnoreturn.h>` header file
- Type-generic expressions using the `_Generic` keyword. For example, the following macro `cbrt(x)` translates to `cbrtl(x)`, `cbrt(x)` or `cbrtf(x)` depending on the type of `x`:

  ```
  #define cbrt(x) _Generic((x), long double: cbrtl, \
                            default: cbrt, \
                            float: cbrtf)(x)
  ```
- Multi-threading support (`_Thread_local` storage-class specifier, `<threads.h>` header including thread creation/management functions, mutex, condition variable and thread-specific storage functionality, as well as the `_Atomic` type qualifier and `<stdatomic.h>` for uninterruptible object access).
- Improved Unicode support based on the C Unicode Technical Report ISO/IEC TR 19769:2004 (`char16_t` and `char32_t` types for storing `UTF-16/UTF-32` encoded data, including conversion functions in `<uchar.h>` and the corresponding u and U string literal prefixes, as well as the u8 prefix for `UTF-8` encoded literals).
- Removal of the `gets` function, deprecated in the previous C language standard revision, ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), in favor of a new safe alternative, `gets_s`.
- Bounds-checking interfaces (Annex K).
- Analyzability features (Annex L).
- More macros for querying the characteristics of floating point types, concerning subnormal floating point numbers and the number of decimal digits the type is able to store.
- Anonymous structures and unions, useful when unions and structures are nested, e.g. in `struct T { int tag; union { float x; int n; }; };`.
- Static assertions, which are evaluated during translation at a later phase than `#if` and `#error`, when types are understood by the translator.
- An exclusive create-and-open mode (`"…x"` suffix) for `open`. This behaves like `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` in `POSIX`, which is commonly used for lock files.
- The `quick_exit` function as a third way to terminate a program, intended to do at least minimal deinitialization if termination with `exit` fails.
- Macros for the construction of complex values (partly because `real + imaginary*I` might not yield the expected value if `imaginary` is infinite or `NaN`).

Answer (score 9):

Per the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) itself, here are the major changes from C99:

> **Foreword**
> ...
> 6     This third edition cancels and replaces the second edition, ISO/IEC 9899:1999, as
> corrected by ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 1:2001, ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 2:2004, and
> ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 3:2007. Major changes from the previous edition include:
>
>      — conditional (optional) features (including some that were previously mandatory)
>
>      — support for multiple threads of execution including an improved memory sequencing
> model, atomic objects, and thread-local storage (**`<stdatomic.h>`** and
> **`<threads.h>`**)
>
>      — additional floating-point characteristic macros (**`<float.h>`**)
>
>      — querying and specifying alignment of objects (**`<stdalign.h>`**, **`<stdlib.h>`**)
>
>      — Unicode characters and strings (**`<uchar.h>`**) (originally specified in
> ISO/IEC TR 19769:2004)
>
>      — type-generic expressions
>
>      — static assertions
>
>      — anonymous structures and unions
>
>      — no-return functions
>
>      — macros to create complex numbers (**`<complex.h>`**)
>
>      — support for opening files for exclusive access
>
>      — removed the **`gets`** function (**`<stdio.h>`**)
>
>      — added the **`aligned_alloc`**, **`at_quick_exit`**, and **`quick_exit`** functions
> (**`<stdlib.h>`**)
>
>      — (conditional) support for bounds-checking interfaces (originally specified in
> ISO/IEC TR 24731−1:2007)
>
>      — (conditional) support for analyzability

Comment: The link is to the N1570 draft of the C11 standard. Some very minor changes were made between that draft and the final released standard.

Comment: The C11 standard itself is only available for purchase so, for people like me, @JohnBode, and the general public, N1570 is the best we've got for C11 (without paying money). See [ISO/IEC 9899 - Programming languages - C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards)