# How come we can pass an array to a function by reference without using pointers

Tags: c, arrays

It is tested and obvious that the following code won't work as we are initialising an array q[][4] with the address of first element of an array a.

```
    int main()
{
    int a[3][4] =
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 0, 1, 6
    } ;
    int q[ ][4]=a;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",q[i][j]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, If we implement the same logic using functions(ie passing address of array a to a formal parameter q[][4] of a function) then it works fine.

```
main( )
{
    int a[3][4] =
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 0, 1, 6
    } ;

    print ( a, 3, 4 ) ;
}

    print ( int q[ ][4], int row, int col )
    {
        int i, j ;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < col ; j++ )
                printf ( "%d ", q[i][j] ) ;
            printf ( "\n" ) ;
        }
        printf ( "\n" ) ;
    }
```

how come it is possible?

Comment: Arrays automatically decay to pointers when they're used as function arguments.

Comment: there's no reference in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int q[ ][4]` in function argument is equivalent to `int (*q)[4]` (pointer to 4-element array of `int`). [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), paragraph 7 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the
>   array type derivation.

Also `a` used for the function argument is converted to a pointer pointing at the first element of the array, which is 4-element array of `int`. N1570 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators. paragraph 3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
>   unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Therefore, the function `print()` can know where the elements of the array is and work with it.

By the way, don't forget to declare functions (or including headers in which they are declared) *before* the line that use the functions.

Comment: While this is a technically correct quotation from the N1570 draft of C11, you chose to reference [one of the only parts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15737472/4520911) (N1570 6.3.2.1 p3) of the draft that differed in meaning from the final.  I would suggest annotating your draft to reflect the changes listed (for myself, I just did a strike-through of the `_Alignof` text anywhere where there was a change) just in case you reference this part again for Stack Overflow, or for personal reference ;-). The only difference in your citation of N1570 6.3.2.1 p3 was _"the `_Alignof` operator"_ part.