# When is it necessary or meaningful to write &f for a function f or *fp for a function pointer fp (except in: sizeof &f)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-pointers

From the C17 standard draft (6.3.2.1 ¶4; footnote removed):

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*".

- According to the footnote which I omitted from the quote above, `sizeof f` (for a function designator `f`) is non-standards-conformant.
- Note that the C11 standard additionally mentions the `_Alignof` operator.
- Note that the C2x draft additionally mentions the `typeof` operator.

As a result (here: `f` is a function designator; `fp` is a function pointer):

1. One can indicate the address of a function as `&f` (explicit) or `f` (short).
2. One can make a function call as:

   - `(&f)(args)` or `f(args)`
   - `fp(args)` or `(*fp)(args)`

Here,

- left-hand `(&f)(args)`/`fp(args)` is consistent with function calls technically operating on function pointers, and
- right-hand `f(args)`/`(*fp)(args)` is consistent with the naive assumption that function calls operate on functions (instead of pointers to functions).

Stylistically,

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6893288/2057969) labels `&f` as "always redundant",
- `(&f)(args)` is virtually unused in practice,
- `f`/`f(args)`/`(*fp)(args)` is the style used in K&R (2e), and
- `f`/`f(args)`/`fp(args)` is the shortest style.

(For completeness' sake (and in case anyone else wants a nice summary), here is a longer list of expressions that are equivalent to `f`: `(&f)`, `(*******f)`, `(***&***f)`, `(***&**&f)`, `(&**&***f)`, `(&**&**&f)`.)

But:
**When is it ever necessary or meaningful to**

- **write `&f` (where `f` is a function designator) or**
- **write `*fp` (where `fp` is a function pointer)?**

(By "meaningful", I mean that the behavior of the program is altered.)

- The only case I am aware of is `sizeof &f`. (`sizeof f` is illegal, even though the GCC dialect of C permits it (at least as of version 12.2.0), but with different semantics: It seemingly returns `1` in all(?) cases. Why?)

  - I don't understand this. Letting `f` auto-convert to `&f` would let us simplify the standard's phrasing and give `sizeof f` useful semantics too. (Perhaps this restriction exists to maintain parallelism with `typeof`, which has been floating around as a compiler extension for a while.)
- Regarding what happened with `_Alignof`, the committee had made a mistake in C11, so they rectified it in C17. Basically: Unlike `sizeof`, `_Alignof` only accepts a parenthesized type as its argument, but not an expression (C11 draft, 6.5.3 ¶1). See also [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51803814/2057969).
- If `typeof` is officially added to C with the next standard, a distinction between `typeof &f`/`typeof fp` and `typeof f`/`typeof *fp` would be obviously meaningful.

Comment: Since this is a language-lawyer question, note that `sizeof f`, where `f` is a function, is not “illegal” or “non-standards-conformant”. It is not *strictly conforming*, but, since there is a C compiler that accepts it, it is *conforming* as defined by C 2018 4 7.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `sizeof f` is however a constraint violation, not as per 6.3 but as per 6.5.3.4 "Constraints - The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete type". In case this would somehow break the behavior of a strictly conforming program (I don't quite see how) then accepting `sizeof f` would mean that the compiler is not conforming.

Comment: @Lundin: No, accepting `sizeof f` would not mean the compiler is not conforming. Not issuing a diagnostic would mean the compiler is not conforming. The compiler merely has to print a message, and then it may accept the program.

Comment: Oh, good point -- I could edit the question to have it say that such *code* would be non-standards-conformant, would that work?

Comment: @LoverofStructure There are also generics (_Generic) - maybe add them to the question as well? (Which btw, I just read - don't make a difference)

Comment: It guess it is meaningful for upcoming `typeof`. One can write `typeof(sin) cos, sqrt;` instead of `double cos(double); double sqrt(double);`.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I am not familiar with the respective potential issue, but please feel free to edit my question or comment/answer otherwise!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not only that but the non-standard extension is not allowed to break a strictly conforming program (by adding extra identifiers etc) or otherwise the compiler is not conforming. But as I said, I don't quite see how that would apply in this case.

Comment: Also notably gcc does _not_ allow `sizeof f` if compiling in strict mode with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @Lundin See my edit just now regarding GCC's dialect of C.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Far as I know `-std=gnuxx` has allowed this forever. Version 12.2 is nothing new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a function designator `f` is automatically converted to the address of the function in many situations, the only times when `f` is semantically different from `&f` is when it is not converted. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 4, these are when it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`. Thus we have:

- `sizeof f` requires a diagnostic message because it violates the constraints in C 2018 6.5.3.4 1 (`sizeof` shall not be applied to an expression with function type) and its behavior is not defined by the C standard (because of the constraint violation), whereas `sizeof &f` yields the size of a pointer to the function. (`sizeof f` is nonetheless *conforming* code per C 2018 4 7, albeit not *strictly conforming*, since there exists a C compiler that accepts it.)
- `&f` yields the address of `f` whereas `& &f` requires a diagnostic message because it violates the constraints in C 2018 6.5.3.2 1 (the operand of unary `&` shall be a function designator, the result of array subscripting or unary `*`, or an lvalue other than a bit-field or one declared with `register`). I am unaware of a C compiler that accepts `& &f`, so this is not strictly conforming code, except to the extent we could imagine and construct a C compiler that accepts it. (The space in `& &f` serves to separate the tokens. Otherwise `&&` is a single token, for the logical AND operator.)

My guess at why GCC accepts `sizeof f` is that it is part of allowing address arithmetic on pointers generally, even `void *` and pointers to functions, to support code used in operating systems, debuggers, program loaders, and similar software that operates on functions and arbitrary memory. Making `sizeof f` be 1 is a part of designing GCC’s arithmetic on function pointers to operate in units of bytes. (This is an unnecessary feature of GCC because we could support arithmetic on pointers to functions and `void *` by requiring they be first converted to a pointer to a character type. However, I suppose it was done to support code practices at the time it was done and is now legacy.)

At a syntax level, `&f` differs from `f` in being longer, so it could run afoul of environmental limits of the compiler. For example, C 2018 5.2.4.1 1 requires a compiler support 4095 characters in a logical source line (in at least one program), so changing `f` to `&f` could push the line over the length that a compiler supports.

With `*fp` versus `fp`, similar reasoning applies: `*fp` is converted to the equivalent of `fp` in many situations, so semantic differences arise only when it is not. So `sizeof *fp` and `sizeof fp` differ as discussed above. However, for `&`, `&*fp` is the address of the function, whereas `&fp` is the address of the pointer. (This supposes that `fp` is an object, not some other expression that is not an lvalue. If it is not an object, it raises the same issues as discussed for `&` above.)

And `*fp` versus `fp` has the same environmental limit consideration as `&f` versus `f`.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting: In declarations, these equivalences don't hold. Most importantly, one can't gratuitously replace `fp` by `*fp`. I am assuming that all is good specification-wise in the standard, but I still find it odd that function calls *technically* operate on function pointers in ordinary code, while function declaration syntax follows the traditional/naive understanding that function calls are done with functions, not pointers thereto.

Comment: "(sizeof f is nonetheless *conforming* code per C 2018 4 7, albeit not *strictly conforming*, since there exists a C compiler that accepts it.)" would seem to balloon the definition of "*conforming* code" to include statements line `fflush (stdin);` because there is a compiler that accepts it -- despite [7.21.5.2(2)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsubsection.7.21.5.2) defining it as UB unless applied to an *output* or *update* stream. I get the intent of your statement, but I worry the "any compiler" test may be contradictory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `fflush(stdin);` is conforming code. The C standard specifies only a base language that is intended to be extended, and even explicit statements that specific things are undefined behavior by the standard are not intended to be prohibitions about defining them. When a C implementation defines `flush(stdin)`, that is a valid extension, and it is conforming code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - thank you. I more fully appreciate the interplay between the standard and implementations and conforming. I had not looked at "*conforming*" in that manner before. It does make sense in an odd way and emphasizes the difference between *conforming* (to the implementation) and *strictly conforming* (to the C standard) and I'm sure there are other *shades of grey* in between.