# Are typedef declarations for bare function types (ie: not function pointers) legal in C89/C90?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-pointers, typedef, kernighan-and-ritchie

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int INTFUNC(char *, char *);
INTFUNC lencmp;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", lencmp("a", "aaa")); /* -1 */
    printf("%d\n", lencmp("aaa", "aaa")); /* 0 */
    printf("%d\n", lencmp("aaa", "a")); /* 1 */

    return 0;
}

int lencmp(char *s, char *t) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(s), len2 = strlen(t);
    return (len1 > len2) - (len1 < len2);
}
```

This compiles fine without warnings with GCC and compiler flags `-std=c90 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

But K&R (2e) don't show such code in their book; they only ever use`typedef`s for function *pointers*. (Their discussion on p147 is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76670287/2057969), but that aspect is not the subject of this question.) I don't have access to the C89/C90 standard documents.

According to the C standards documents (C99 TC3 (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3) draft, 6.7.7 ¶7; C11 draft, 6.7.8 ¶7; C17 draft, 6.7.8 ¶7; text identical (modulo formatting) in all three documents):

> All three of the following declarations of the `signal` function [from `<signal.h>`] specify exactly the same type, the first without making use of any typedef names.
>
> ```
> typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int);
>
> void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
> fv *signal(int, fv *);
> pfv signal(int, pfv);
> ```

For what it's worth, [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Function_pointer&oldid=1150118432#Alternate_C_and_C++_syntax):

> [example C++ code with `typedef`s for function pointers:]
>
> ```
> [...]
> typedef int(Foo::*Foo_pfn)(int,int);
> [...]
> typedef int(*PFN)(int);
> [...]
> ```
>
> ## Alternate C and C++ syntax
>
> The C and C++ syntax [with `typedef`s for function pointer types] given above is the canonical one used in all the textbooks - but it's difficult to read and explain. Even the above `typedef` examples use this syntax. However, every C and C++ compiler supports a more clear and concise mechanism to declare function pointers: use `typedef`, but *don't* store the pointer as part of the definition. Note that the only way this kind of `typedef` can actually be used is with a pointer - but that highlights the pointer-ness of it.
>
> ### C and C++
>
> ```
> [...]
> typedef int Fn(char c);
> [...]
> typedef Fn *PFn;
> [...]
> ```
>
> ### C++
>
> [...]

Their wording ("canonical" vs "every C and C++ compiler supports") can be understood to have the discursive/conversational [implicature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) that allowing `typedef`s for bare function types is a compiler extension and not sanctioned by the standards. But is that really so? (One commenter argues that such an implicature is absent.) My quote from the C99 TC3, C11, and C17 standards clearly demonstrates that such `typedef`s are legal at least since C99 TC3. Given that K&R (2e) doesn't contain `typedef` examples in this style, I wonder: **Are `typedef` declarations for bare function types (ie: not function pointers) legal in C89/C90?** Note that the example "given above" that Wikipedia refers to (not shown in its entirety here) is a C++ example, so it's also possible that it's always been legal in standard C but just not in (some versions of) C++.

Finally, if Wikipedia's characterization of using `typedef`s for function pointers as "canonical" is correct, the reason for that might lie in the conspicuous lack of `typedef`s for bare function types in K&R (2e).

Comment: Function types are perfectly legal since the dawn of C. `int foo(int)` tell that `foo` is of type `int(int)`.

Comment: @tstanisl Right, but this question is about their use in `typedef`s. There have traditionally been some restrictions on functions, like for arrays: You can't have functions directly as function arguments, you can't have direct function return values, and you can't store functions in an array directly – in all of these cases you need to use function pointers instead, at least in terms of the declared types (in some cases [automatic conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76217910/2057969) takes care of this).

Comment: Functions are not object thus then cannot be placed in arrays or structs or accessed via `memcpy`. Functions can be declared to take function parameters. Those will be automatically adjusted to function pointers so `void foo(int(int))` is transformed to `void foo(int (*)(int))`. A similar mechanics to "array decay". The `typedef`s works like declarations. The `typedef` behaves a bit like `storace-class modifier`. Why function types should behave differently for `typedef`s?

Comment: See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt. Grep for `typedef int F(void)`

Comment: Re “The implication of their phrasing is that allowing `typedef`s for bare function types is a compiler extension but not sanctioned by the standards”: There is no such implication in the quoted passage. The passage shows a typedef being made for a bare function type (`typedef int Fn(char c);`) and does not say it is not specified or not allowed by a standard. What you cannot do, in the sense it is not specified by the C or C++ standards, is define a function using this typedef (as in `Fn MyFunction { return 0; }`), but the passage does not show any compiler extension that does support that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think there might be a misunderstanding: The first quoted paragraph refers to some examples *before the quoted section* which I didn't bother to reproduce here (but not to `typedef int Fn(char c);`). Them then saying "every C and C++ compiler supports" does suggest that it's an unofficial extension (not as a strict logical implication, but it's an [implicature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) in discourse).

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Re “Them then saying "every C and C++ compiler supports" does suggest that it's an unofficial extension”: No, it does not. Further, regardless of what the author of that passage is trying to say, defining a typedef for a function type is specified by the C standard and is specified by the C++ standard. Bonus note: It is inappropriate for the Wikipedia page to assert “The C and C++ syntax… given above is the canonical one used in all the textbooks,” as that is clearly an overly broad assertion without citation. Avoid using Wikipedia to interpret technical documents.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If that were so (no implicature), they should just write "the (C/C++) standard(s) support". // In the passage they are clearly contrasting 'direct function type' with 'with pointer', not 'definition-less declaration' with 'definition' of a function.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: That section of the Wikipedia page is poorly written. Avoid using Wikipedia to interpret technical documents. You can contact the author and explain to them what they ought to write. The C and C++ standards speak for themselves, and both support defining a typedef for a function type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I also don't see so many `typedef`s for direct function types in the wild, but my exposure is just one small dataset. Either way, it's better to ground a question about the standard in an assertion on Wikipedia than on my personal experience (plus, I didn't have the C89/C90 standard at hand).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re "What you cannot do, in the sense it is not specified by the C or C++ standards, [...]": the quoted C89 excerpt by user 'tstanisl' (see their answer) actually explicitly outlaws this ("syntax/constraint error"); ie it's not "not specified". Maybe you meant "not sanctioned".

Comment: @LoverofStructure: The C standard’s “constraints” are a rhetorical device used for stating what it does not and does not define. They are not a prohibition on what code programmers may write. The overall framework for this is laid out in clauses 1 and 4. In paragraphs 5 through 7 of clause 4, the 2018 C standard defines a *conforming program* to be one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation, where a *conforming implementation* is one that accepts any *strictly conforming program*. (Similar text appears in C 1990.) …

Comment: … Thus, while the rules specify various “constraints” about code for which some behavior is specified, those constraints apply to strictly conforming code. The standard allows additional conforming code, so it is incorrect to state the standard “outlaws” such code. Any compiler extension that does not alter the behavior of strictly conforming code is conforming code as specified by the C standard, regardless of syntax or constraints. Further, the C standard is wholly voluntary and has no legal, physical, or ethical control over humans and therefore cannot “outlaw” anything.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My usage of the verb "to outlaw" is a rhetorical device too! The bottom line is, while I agree with nearly everything I've seen you write, here and elsewhere, I don't agree with your view on Wikipedia's *implicature*. (That was the linguist in me: we generally call logical implications "entailment", and "implication" for us often refers to conversational implicatures – admittedly not clear in this context.) I did make an edit to my question in this regard, to weaken/clarify my wording. Btw if you have opinions on the downvotes on this and my previous question, do let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254479/discussion-between-lover-of-structure-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are typedef declarations to bare function types (ie: not function pointers) legal in C89/C90?

YES.

See [C89 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt):

> 3.7.1 Function definitions
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
>      function-definition:
>              declaration-specifiers<opt> declarator
>                        declaration-list<opt> compound-statement
> ```
>
> Constraints
>
> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name
> of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the
> declarator portion of the function definition./70/

Footnote 70:

> The intent is that the top type in a function definition cannot be
> inherited from a typedef:

```
typedef int F(void); /* type F is ``function
of no arguments returning int '' */
F f, g; /* f and g both have type
compatible with F */
F f { /*...*/ } /* WRONG: syntax/constraint error
*/
F g() { /*...*/ } /* WRONG: declares that g returns a function */
int f(void) { /*...*/ } /* RIGHT: f has type compatible with F */
int g() { /*...*/ } /* RIGHT: g has type compatible with F */
F *e(void) { /*...*/ } /* e returns a pointer to a function */
F *((e))(void) { /*...*/ } /* same: parentheses irrelevant */
int (*fp)(void); /* fp points to a function that has type F */
F *Fp; /* Fp points to a function that has type F */
```

The first line proves that the `typedef`ing function types is accepted by C89 standard.